# JQuery Datepicker previous and next icons not showing up in JQuery Tabs element?

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-tabs

For some reason, the `previous` and `next` icons in jQuery Datepicker aren't showing up when I insert a datepicker within a jQuery Tabs element. CSS is also impacted. Here's a screenshot:

[JQuery Calendar Potential Issue When Embedded in JQuery Tabs Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8if85.png)

[image]

Comment: Great, now what about showing us your code?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not copy the Images (icon srites) from your downloaded jQuery build to your project. it must be (relatively to your jquery-ui.min.css) in a folder called "images". the icon sprites are named like so: "images/ui-icons_HEXCOLOR_256x240.png". Add them into the correct path and it will be okay.